# Deserialize Yaml into c# collection

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

I have the following yaml structure:

```
TestPaySignService:
    Test:
        TestString:
            settings-key: TestStringValue
            types:
                - type1
                - type2

        TestString2:
            settings-key: TestStringValue2
            types:
                - type1
                - type2
```

I want to parse this yaml and store only "settings-key" and "types" together in c# collection, for example List, like the following:

```
[
  {
     name: TestStringValue,
     types: ["type1", "type2"]
  },
  {
     name: TestStringValue2,
     types: ["type1", "type2"]
  }
]
```

I've followed the follwin question and tried the accepted answer's code, but as it seems it's obsolete for now: [Deserialize a YAML "Table" of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894438/deserialize-a-yaml-table-of-data)

P.S. my yaml schema changes every time, but "settings-key" and "types" are always contained, so I want to create something like "dynamic parser"

Comment: What did you try? What do you mean `obsolete`? You can load the structure in whatever way you want and then flatten/transform it using LINQ

Comment: "You can load the structure in whatever way you want and then flatten/transform it using LINQ"

please look at my second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535791/c-sharp-get-all-property-conditionally-from-dynamic-collection-which-looks-like?noredirect=1#comment90039457_51535791

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing YAML using YamlDotNet when the root node of each object is named using it's ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146291/deserializing-yaml-using-yamldotnet-when-the-root-node-of-each-object-is-named-u)

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize the yaml to a dynamic object then walk a bit. Something like the following:

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NSB5uh)

```
public static void Main()
{
    var r = new StringReader(@"TestPaySignService:
Test:
    TestString:
        settings-key: TestStringValue
        types:
            - type1
            - type2

    TestString2:
        settings-key: TestStringValue2
        types:
            - type1
            - type2"); 
    var deserializer = new Deserializer();
    var yamlObject = deserializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(r)["TestPaySignService"]["Test"].Values;

    // just to print the json
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, yamlObject);
}
```

Output

```
[{
    "settings-key": "TestStringValue",
    "types": [
        "type1",
        "type2"
    ]
},
{
    "settings-key": "TestStringValue2",
    "types": [
        "type1",
        "type2"
    ]
}]
```

If you need to use TestString, you should deserialize it into an object.

Comment: thanks, but when yaml schema is more "deeper" then it's a bit complicated. please review my second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535791/c-sharp-get-all-property-conditionally-from-dynamic-collection-which-looks-like?noredirect=1#comment90039457_51535791